# Alternative to creating a new boto3 client for each route in Flask/Fastapi? (multi organizations)

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, fastapi

I am developing a fastapi api but it would also apply to flask. Users can login and get a token containing aws credentials. Once logged in, they can do more requests to our api. Many of those requests are calling aws api.

How do I handle the boto3 clients? At the moment, I'm initializing it inside each routes, which slows the api greatly. How could I store the clients dynamically ? Should I have a global variable and store them in memory and when using the route, I "check" if a client has already been created ? It sounds wrong. Is there an alternative?

Thanks

Comment: In what way does creating the boto clients slow down anything? They are very cheap to create.

Comment: They're cheap to create after the first one. The first one is expensive, because it parses all the JSON and builds the internal data structures, but that should be cached once it's loaded...

Comment: first, cached...where? and second does it cache them even though there are different users with different accounts/clients?